# Access spring security through kubernetes ingress

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-service, kubernetes-security

I enabled in my backend tls. So every traffic needs to go through "https://.....".
I am able to access it locally or with Port-Forwarding in Kubernetes.
But I cannot access it through the DNS (e.g. https://hostname.net/backend/....).

I get as answer:

```
Bad Request
This combination of host and port requires TLS.
```

I read that the certificates could be wrong, but with port-forwarding everything works, so I don't think this could be the problem. Certificates are self-signed. I have only on my server certificates.

Before I add tls, everythinkg works fine.

Here is my service and my ingress:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: app-Core
  namespace: namespace
spec:
  clusterIP: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: core
    app.kubernetes.io/name: app
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
----------------------------------
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
  name: core-app-core
  namespace: namespace
spec:
  rules:
  - host: hostname
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: app-Core
          servicePort: 8080
        path: /backend(/|$)(.*)
      - backend:
          serviceName: app-Core
          servicePort: 8080
        path: /camunda(/|$)(.*)
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Comment: If your upstream only listens on TLS, you'll need to tell your Ingress resource about that [via the `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"` annotation](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#backend-protocol)

Comment: Great! Thanks @mdaniel. It solved my problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: https` annontation to your ingress definition.

Using  `backend-protocol`  annotations is possible to indicate how NGINX should communicate with the backend service.
By default NGINX uses  `HTTP`.

Take a look: [ingress-tls](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/tls/), [backend-protocol](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#backend-protocol).